# How to programmatically disable onClick handler on Android AppWidget Button

Tags: android, layout, android-widget

I have a Button on appwidget, that I need to 'enable'/'disable' programmatically from a Service.

First idea was to call `setBoolean(R.id.buttonid, "setClickable", false)` to disable it, but apparently you can't call `setClickable` remotely.

Another idea was was remove the text label from it with `rv.setTextViewText(R.id.buttonid, "")` and then remove the click handler by `rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonid, null)`. Unfortunately passing `null` to it causes `NullPointerException` in in `android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs`

Is there some other way to programmatically disable/enable appwidget Button? I could just call `rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonid, View.GONE)` to hide the button completely instead of disabling it. This would however completely break whole widget layout and I would like to avoid it.

The solution I'm using now is hiding the button with `setViewVisibility` and showing other blank button instead to the keep appwidget layout as it was before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your `RemoteViews` instance, you supply a layout. When you want to disable the button, choose a layout with `android:enabled="false"` on that button.

Or, you could use `setOnClickPendingIntent()` and supply an `Intent` that just will not go anywhere (e.g., a broadcast `Intent` for an action that nobody uses).

Answer (score 9):

Basically I had the same problem, but wanted to do it entirely programmatic, so we just pass the boolean value to the `setBoolean()` function:

```
remoteViews.setBoolean(R.id.imageButton1, "setEnabled", false);
```

Don't forget to tell Android to update the home screen:

```
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getResources().getText(R.string.package_name).toString(), R.layout.your_layout);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```