# Can't disable android.widget.Button

Tags: android

I have a button inside Android widget, declared like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/newWorkBtnWidget"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/ts_on_repair"/>
```

Every time I try to enable or disable this button via RemoteViews I get an error `android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: view: android.widget.Button can't use method with RemoteViews: setEnabled(boolean)`

My code:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.widget);

remoteViews.setInt(R.id.newWorkBtnWidget, "setBackgroundResource",
    R.drawable.green_button);
remoteViews.setBoolean(R.id.newWorkBtnWidget, 
   "setEnabled", false);
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Eh, what is it, `newWorkBtnWidget` or `newWorkButtWidget`?

Comment: Sorry, this should be the same button, fixed. Anyway this is not related to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem recently, and I found that remoteView.setBoolean() with methodname 'setEnabled' doesn't work either.

use

```
remoteViews.setBoolean(R.id.textView_life_id, "setEnabled", true);
```

will get error like this

```
W/AppWidgetHostView: updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
                                              android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: view: android.widget.TextView can't use method with RemoteViews: setEnabled(boolean)
                                                  at android.widget.RemoteViews$ReflectionAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1134)
                                                  at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2304)
                                                  at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2263)
                                                  at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:402)
                                                  at com.android.launcher2.LauncherAppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(LauncherAppWidgetHostView.java:54)
                                                  at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.updateAppWidgetView(AppWidgetHost.java:434)
                                                  at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetHost.java:102)
                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5089)
                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

finally I found the answer is that only **method in SDK with @android.view.RemotableViewMethod** can be used in remoteview.

like

```
@android.view.RemotableViewMethod
public final void setText(CharSequence text) {
     setText(text, mBufferType);
}
```

then you can use views.setCharSequence(R.id.textView, "setText", "Test");

Answer (score 0):

You can't use enabled/disabled in the traditional sense, but you can either update the Button to have the look of disabled, or have a "false" button, and switch them out with GONE/VISIBLE.

Comment: I'm suprised, because a few sources on the web list mentioned by me way of disabling as a possibility, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15413357/685948